# CSS grid moving items instead of overlapping z-index

Tags: html, css, z-index, css-grid, layer

I'm creating a sprite based game using HTML5 & CSS grid.
I've set different z-index for different elements ( background and foreground )

Expectation:
 I imagined that multiple elements could occupy the same grid space, but apparently, they're moved around, ignoring the z-index.

Result: Changing the foreground element's grid-area shifts the order of remaining items instead of overlapping them

[image: Changing the foreground element's grid-area shifts the order of remaining items instead of overlapping them]

CSS:

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 1px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 20%);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 20%);
}

.item {
    z-index: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-size: 1600%;
    image-rendering: pixelated;
}

@keyframes walk {
    100% { background-position: -462px; }
}

#sprite {
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: transparent;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: url(./../assets/thief.png) 0px 0px;
    background-size: 1200%;
    image-rendering: pixelated;
    animation: walk 0.5s steps(5) infinite;
}
```

Comment: the position of the element in the grid is being generated by editing the style:
`{
        gridColumn: ${this.state.hero.c},
        gridRow: ${this.state.hero.r},
    }`

Comment: Do you the rest of the code or a fiddle for that ?  Why is the sprite's position set to outside of the grid sometimes ?

Answer (score 1):

Initial quick and dirty way below using absolute position – but having just  looked into this more, it seems you can achieve overlaying grid cells by using custom column and row names with `grid-template-areas` and positioning them with `grid-area`.

```css
    .container {
        height: 500px;
        width: 500px;
        position: relative;
        display: grid;
        grid-gap: 5px;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 20%);
        grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 20%);
        grid-template-areas: "r1c1 r1c2 r1c3 r1c4 r1c5"
            "r2c1 r2c2 r2c3 r2c4 r2c5"
            "r3c1 r3c2 r3c3 r3c4 r3c5"
            "r4c1 r4c2 r4c3 r4c4 r4c5"
            "r5c1 r5c2 r5c3 r5c4 r5c5";
    }

    .item {
        background: #eee;
        padding: .25em;
        z-index: 0;
    }

    #sprite {
      grid-area: r2c3;
      background: #ccc;
      z-index: 5;
      opacity: .5;
    }

    /* positioning the overlapped cell so the grid flow is intact */
    /* you'll need to specify all the other cell classes also! */
    .r2c3 {
        grid-area: r2c3;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div id="sprite">sprite</div>
    <div class="item r1c1">1</div>
    <div class="item r1c2">2</div>
    <div class="item r1c3">3</div>
    <div class="item r1c4">4</div>
    <div class="item r1c5">5</div>
    <div class="item r2c1">6</div>
    <div class="item r2c2">7</div>
    <div class="item r2c3">8</div>
    <div class="item r2c4">9</div>
    <div class="item r2c5">10</div>
    <div class="item r3c1">11</div>
    <div class="item r3c2">12</div>
    <div class="item r3c3">13</div>
    <div class="item r3c4">14</div>
    <div class="item r3c5">15</div>
    <div class="item r4c1">16</div>
    <div class="item r4c2">17</div>
    <div class="item r4c3">18</div>
    <div class="item r4c4">19</div>
    <div class="item r4c5">20</div>
    <div class="item r5c1">21</div>
    <div class="item r5c2">22</div>
    <div class="item r5c3">23</div>
    <div class="item r5c4">24</div>
    <div class="item r5c5">25</div>
</div>
```

Quick and dirty option – for any overlaying elements (like the player sprite) you can absolute position them to remove them from the grid layout. For example:

```
#sprite {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Hi Paul,

I managed to rescue it with:
`
#sprite {
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
}
`
Thanks for the suggestion!